# Modify notifications in Phonegap and Pushwoosh

Tags: cordova, notifications, pushwoosh

I'm currently working on PhoneGap and Pushwoosh and have some questions:

1. Is it possible to change the text / icon of the notification in the status bar?
2. If yes, is it also possible to show the notification only when you have received some specified data?

Comment: I think this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000809/how-to-statusbar-notification-using-phone-gap-push-plugin

Comment: thank you very much, but i have already downloaded this example https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-3-sample-app and it also works. the problem is that the notification only should be shown when there is specified data and i want to change the text of the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to modify SDK for that as this functionality unfortunately is not available out of the box. If you don't mind doing some Java coding it would be rather easy.

You might need to modify this file:

https://github.com/shaders/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin/blob/master/src/android/src/com/arellomobile/android/push/PushGCMIntentService.java

This function:

private static void generateNotification(Context context, Intent intent, Handler handler)