# Filtering Push-Notifications Client-Side Pushwoosh

Tags: cordova, push-notification, filtering, pushwoosh

I am using Pushwoosh Remote API with PhoneGap(Android). I want to filter the Push Notifications client-side. So if a Push Notification comes, the Notifications should not be shown, but first the custom data in the Notifications  should be compared with the selection the user did. So if the user is qualified to see the Notification, the Notifications should be shown. I don´t know how I can realize that. This filtering should be client-side.

I am glad of any solution I get!
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using Pushwoosh tags for this (filtering on the server side).
However if you need to do filtering client side - see my answer to this question:

[Modify notifications in Phonegap and Pushwoosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840956/modify-notifications-in-phonegap-and-pushwoosh/21239118#21239118)